# Capturing MSBuild.exe output in a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, msbuild, build-script

I'm creating some new build scripts for a project using PowerShell, and would like to capture the output of MSBuild when I call it and save that to a text file.  I've tried a couple different methods of doing so with no luck so far--here's what I last tried (Write-Buildlog just handles writing off the output to the log):

> Start-Process $msBuildExecutable $buildArgs -Wait | Write-Buildlog

No output at all is captured, though MSBuild runs fine.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated as I've done a bit of searching and have found nothing useful so far, which is surprising :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pipe output from msbuild to a logging or processing cmdlet, you should not be starting it with `Start-Process`, just execute it normally.

```
PS> msbuild.exe $flag1 $flag2 $thingToBuild | Write-Buildlog
```

You might need to also redirect stderr to capture more of the output.  In that case you would need to add `2>&1`

```
PS> msbuild.exe $flag1 $flag2 $thingToBuild  2>&1 | Write-Buildlog
```

`Start-Process` will start your process outside of any powershell environment or hosting, so obtaining output and sending to cmdlets becomes much more difficult.  If you want to process executable output in powershell, then it's best to simply stay within a powershell environment the whole time.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to work either:

$msBuildExecutable + $buildArgs 2>&1 | Write-BuildLog

Doesn't even seem to be running MSBuild?

Comment: More detail--I'm looking to run a specific version of MSBuild, which is why I have it in a variable.  But it doesn't appear that I can run it in the way your are proposing, which is why I was using Start-Process in the first place--is there another way I can do this without Start-Process then?

Comment: Also just tried:  & $msBuildExecutable $buildArgs 2>&1 | Write-BuildLog   still nothing

Comment: If your args are in an array, you need to use "splatting" to pass them to an executable that expects them one-at-a-time. `PS> & $pathToMsBuild @buildArgs`

Comment: They're not in an array, just a string.

Comment: However you are constructing the string, instead use the same inputs to construct an array.  Or if it's only a couple of arguments, just pass them one-at-a time like `PS> & $msbuildPath $arg1 $arg2 ...`

Answer (score 2):

In `Start-Process` CmdLet you've got a `-RedirectStandardOutput` parameter ; have you test it ?

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\ping.exe" -ArgumentList "MyMachine" -RedirectStandardOutput "c:\temp\p.txt" -NoNewWindow
```

You can also redirect errors with `-RedirectStandardError`

Comment: Thanks!  But I want to send the output to my Write-Buildlog cmdlet, which it doesn't look like -RedirectStandardError can do?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is:

```
& msbuild.exe .\yourproj.sln |Out-Host
```

or even:
    & msbuild.exe .\yourproj.sln |Out-File c:\log.txt

If writing to a file is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want with the output if you run it like this:

```
$MSBuild = [string](MSBuild.exe -argument1 -argument2 -andSoOn)
```

Say you want to have the output go to a file.

```
$MSBuild = [string](MSBuild.exe -argument1 -argument2 -andSoOn) | Out-File C:\text.txt
```

Or write it like so...

```
$MSBuild = [string](MSBuild.exe -argument1 -argument2 -andSoOn) 2>&1 >> C:\text.txt
```

Note: 2 ">>" means to append and 1 ">" to overwrite previously added lines.

Or if you want just to get a just one word like "true" from a bunch of output.

```
$MSBuild = [string](MSBuild.exe -argument1 -argument2 -andSoOn)
if($MSBuid -match "true") 
{
    Write-Host "Whatever you want to say about what's true"
}
```

If you want to see it all in the console, you could do this.

```
$MSBuild = [string](MSBuild.exe -argument1 -argument2 -andSoOn) | Out-Host
```

Or...

```
$MSBuild = [string](MSBuild.exe -argument1 -argument2 -andSoOn)
Write-Host $MSBuild
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should read about the Logging options in MsBuild command line:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx

Msbuild /Logger gives you good options to log output. You can use this argument in your powershell script.